# How do I clear the input field after an incorrect entry

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I have an input form name password below, and I would like to clear it after it submits and there is an incorrect password.  I am trying e.target.password.value = '' below also tried e.target.password.value.reset() but I get an error that says that reset is not a function.

```
onPasswordSubmit = (e) => {
    axios.get('/api/password/').then(response => {
      const password = response.data[0].password;
      ((password === this.state.password) ? this.setState(() => ({
        passwordVerified: true,
        error: ''
      })) : this.setState(() => ({
        error: 'Incorrect Password',
      })));
      (this.state.passwordVerified) ? (this.props.changeState()) :
        null
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="input-field col s12">
        <form
          onSubmit={(e) => {
            e.preventDefault()
            this.onPasswordSubmit(e);
            e.target.password.value = ''

        }}>
              <input
                id="password"
                name="password"
                type="password"
                autoFocus
                value={this.state.password}
                onChange={this.onPasswordChange}
              />
              <label htmlFor="password" className='active'>Password</label>
              <br></br>
              <br></br>
              <br></br>
              <Button buttonLabel='Enter'/>


        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: which documentation told you to use .reset() function ?

Comment: `e.target.password` doesn't make sense too...

Comment: Check this out.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187980/clearing-a-input-field-if-it-is-invalid

Comment: `onPasswordSubmit` is this function get called, because I don't see `<input type="submit" />` anywhere

Comment: @ThusithaMalshan, that link contains jQuery,  jQuery shouldn't be used with React

Comment: e.target.password works, gets the right info, and value gets cleared, just doesn't clear the input.  Yes  onSubmitPassword gets called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your input has a value from `state` so you need to use `setState` to clear the password state

Clear the state after request successfully done

```
onPasswordSubmit = (e) => {
    axios.get('/api/password/').then(response => {

      const password = response.data[0].password;
      ((password === this.state.password) ? this.setState(() => ({
        passwordVerified: true,
        error: '',
        password: '', //if success

      })) : this.setState(() => ({
        error: 'Incorrect Password',
        password: '', //if error

      })));
      (this.state.passwordVerified) ? (this.props.changeState()) :
        null
    })
  }
```

Comment: Thank you!  I was trying to set state in onSubmit below, but that wasn't working, works here though.

Comment: Yes if you clear the state in `onSubmit` function it will pass an empty string to `onPasswordSubmit` so the appropriate place to clear the state is after the request successfully done.